# Проблема с обновлением Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, update, apt-get

Собственно что случилось. Вчера (15-04-2015) обновлялся нормально без косяков:

```
sudo -s
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Всегда так обновляюсь. Поставил пару софтин Gitg, NetBeans IDE, Localize(или как-то так).
Все было пучком. Ноут выключил. Утром пришел на работу и при попытке сделать обновиться тем же способом получил вывод:

```
Настраивается пакет initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) …
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Обрабатываются триггеры для initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета initramfs-tools (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Вот эта строчка */etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd* - это файлик */etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-flash-touch-initrd*
Этом файлике вызывается другой скрипт */usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd* - которого там тупо нету!!!

И я даже не предстваляю как он должен выглядеть и что в нем написано должно быть. На рабочих системах вообще ничего похожего не встречалось. И там таких фалов точно нету. Уже проверял.
До этого момента я вообще об их существовании ни сном ни духом.

При попытке сделать

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Вывод точно такой же. Куда копать не знаю уже.

В чем может быть проблема?! Ткните носом куда копать! Гугл ничего путного не выдает.

Comment: Может, у Вас место закончилось? Что выводит `df -h`?

Comment: df -i кстати тоже стоит на всякий

Comment: Судя по выводам команд с местом у меня все ок. Вот [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q37cx81wyood5xz/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_001.png?dl=0)

Comment: Ругается `initramfs-tools`, попробуйте его перенастроить: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools`

Comment: Вывод был вот такой:

/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: Пакет initramfs-tools сломан или установлен не полностью

Comment: Давайте удалим его без удаления зависимостей: `sudo dpkg --remove initramfs-tools`, а затем попробуем установить: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Те же помидоры только с боку. Вот [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws1p7cdcjhwmvkq/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_002.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо одному [человеку](https://toster.ru/user/merryjane)! Разобрался. После удаления папки **/etc/initramfs/post-update.d** сразу все заработало! Причем как она там оказалась и почему после ее удаления к ней перестало идти обращение мне до сих пор не ясно. Если кто вкурсе, то подскажите откуда она там могла взяться.